# A word for breathable in the spirit of potable and edible

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, synonyms

What would be the appropriate choice to use instead of *breathable* in line of edible and potable?

Comment: The proper word is [*breathable*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/breathable). Its opposite is [unbreathable](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unbreathable).  Why would you not want to use it?

Comment: The question appears to be backwards. Breathable *is* the analogue of "edible" and "potable". Perhaps you mean to ask what word is to "breathable" as "eatable" is to "edible", in which case [Aluna's suggestion](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/208426/63503) of "inhalable" seems appropriate (though it's hard to imagine that that means anything other than "gaseous").

Answer (score 6):

***Respirable*** is the right word. It is used in medicine and toxicology also.

> fit for breathing
>
> *respirable air*
>
> <sub>http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/respirable</sub>

Though, you can use ***breathable*** in the right context too.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the word "inhalable" depending on the context.

Comment: Even carbon monoxide is *inhalable*. That is the problem with it.  The OP needs a word which means *safely inhalable*.

Answer (score -1):

The language of the UK's *Health & Safety at Work Act* is ***non-hazardous***.

Comment: But that applies to any, well, non-hazardous thing and isn't specific to gasses that won't kill you.